# Show html spans for certain users only in Django

Tags: django

```
    {% if show_approval %}
            <span>Approvals</span></a>
    {% endif %}
```

I've to create this certain if condition in the html, where this Approvals would be visible for certain users, i've code for this in the python file

```
 context_data = {'show_approval': self.is_approval_supported()}
```

I've to write a function to show it for this user only.

```
where request.user == 'abcd@mail.com'
```

i'm not sure how should i be writing this, i tried like this, but it ain't working.

```
def is_approval_supported(request,self):
    if request.user == 'abcd@mail.com':
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: So is there any error or?

Comment: @ilyasbbu no erros but i'm unable to see the html span even after logging in as that user

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here:

> if request.user == 'abcd@mail.com':

`request.user` returns an object of the current user type (Basically if you see the type `<class 'django.utils.functional.SimpleLazyObject'>`
), not a string.

So try to use like this instead:

```
if request.user.email == 'abcd@mail.com':
```